# How to delete an element in Figma

Tags: figma

I'm pretty new to Figma and web design in general and I duplicated an element and then decided to delete the duplicate but surprisingly there wasn't a delete button, after a 5 minute Google search I was really surprised to find no one's talked about it, in short how do I delete an item/element in Figma.

Comment: through the hamburger menu, and down to Help sections. you can look for available shortcuts keys in Figma. I happened to just found (depending on your system) cmd+x to cut the element. so I use it to remove the element.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming and is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: it is about programming FIgma is a declarative and programmatic tool to build UI

Answer (score 9):

Select an element, then hit backspace to delete.

Comment: Note: You may have to detach the element before delete works. If you don't, pressing backspace will result in a weird focus shift (Figma bug?).